# Using R Shell to Run Unix Installation Commands on Windows

Tags: r, windows

I want to to install bibutils using R on my pc. With unix/ubuntu, I can use "sudo apt-get install bibutils" which works great. I tried using R shell to do the same:

```
shell('sudo apt-get install bibutils')
```

and got the following errors:

```
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c sudo apt-get install 
bibutils' had status 1 
2: In shell("sudo apt-get install bibutils") :
'sudo apt-get install bibutils' execution failed with error code 1
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: try the `system2()` function

Comment: Windows and Linux are two different OSes. You can't run commands from one on the other.